# Checking variable number of If-statements

Tags: autohotkey

I retrieve a string with a series of file-extensions from an Ini-file to an array.
Essentially, I want to check if my variable %ext% is equal to any of these file extensions in an array. For clarification, I don't know ahead of time how many the items will be.

I know I'm explaining this poorly so I'll try to shed some light with pseudo code

```
ext := jpg ;(for example)
IniRead, extsFromFile, data.ini, Images, Extensions
StringSplit, allExts, extsFromFile, `,
If (ext = <any of the elements in the array allExts>)
    doStuff()
```

I'm drawing a blank on how to solve this in Autohotkey. I'm not as familiar with the language as I would like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StringSplit gives you the last element's index (or length, depending on how you look at it) in the form of OutputVar0.  You can loop through, using the built-in A_Index variable to check each element for a match.

```
ext := "jpg" ;(for example)
IniRead, extsFromFile, data.ini, Images, Extensions

; For debugging/testing purposes
extsFromFile = png,bmp,tiff,jpg


StringSplit, allExts, extsFromFile, `,
Loop %allExts0% 
    If (ext = allExts%A_Index%) 
        MsgBox Match! We have %allExts0% extensions and "%ext%" was the %A_Index%th
```

Gives

> Match! We have 4 extensions and "jpg" was the 4th

Answer (score 1):

**The Code:**

```
ext := "jpg"
found := "false"

Loop, read, ExtsList.txt ;this loops reads each line of the file...
{
    If ext = %A_LoopReadLine% ; A_LoopReadLine is the value of the current line...
    {
        msgbox, Found "%ext%" in "ExtsList.txt" at line "%A_Index%"...
        ;call function "dostuff()"
        found := "true"
    }
}

if found = false
{
msgbox, Did not find "%ext%" in "ExtsList.txt"...
}
```

**ExtsList.txt**

```
png
svg
xml
jpg
html
txt
```

Good Luck! :D

Comment: Thanks, but not quite what I was looking for. I have more stuff stored in the INI-file and hence don't want to parse it in its entirety.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into it.. May I see the ini file? My email is on my profile. :)